# how to run cmd and write commandsr with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

so i want to open cmd using javascript node js or electron js and write some commands and exicute them how can i do it ?
thank u in advance

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>vedios infos </h1>
    <input type="file" accept="video/*">
    <script>
        shell.run("%windir%\system32\cmd.exe");

    </script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do this in a HTML document. You can use [`Process`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/process.html)

Comment: I would recommend starting with a primer in npm based projects and writing js for node. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment